# Class as a Popup for Android App

Tags: java, android, xml

I have: 
MainActivity.java, 
Food.java (with layout food.xml), 
food.xml (in GridView)

In my MainActivity class, I have a button where I want a popup to show up after clicking it. I am able to show a xml file as a popup, or move screens to another class, but is there a way to show the Food.java class as the content of the popup?

Also, the Food.java has a GridView with an ImageAdapter

Comment: which xml u r showing as pop up?food.xml?

Comment: food.xml, and it works to create a popup with this
but the thing i want to do is show the class Food.java. Food.java already has the layout food.xml

Comment: Have you read the documentation of the PopupWindow class from the API ? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html

Comment: yup. I have:
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
   View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.food, null);  
   final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Comment: and I need sth like popupWindow.setContentView(someView); but this someView must be a layoutInflator, so I cant make that to reference a class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start  an activity as a dialog using the following,and you can add custom animations on how to show the activity.

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

Comment: one more question in addition, after adding this, its nice in dialog format now, but the background jumps to the main screen of the phone itself. Is there a way to set that?

Comment: can u explain i didn't understand

Comment: yup. so you're method worked perfectly. but when the popup shows up, the background (not the background of the popup, but the background BEHIND the popup) changes from the MainActivity screen to the home screen of the android phone. Is there a way to change that so the background stays as the MainActivity screen?

Comment: can check whether you are using finish() on button click...
if you call finish on that button click then the activity will be closed otherwise the activity wont getclosed and you can see that activity as the background.So remove finish() from the button click if u are using it

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewSwitcher for that. you can create Button in 1st part of ViewSwitcher and rest of the content in the second part and name it food.xml.

For more help see:- http://sampleprogramz.com/android/viewswitcher.php